# How to change link color after it's clicked?

Tags: html, css

Have a link.
With this style:

```
a {
  color: #999;
  &:hover { color: #008da0; }
  &:visited { color: #999; } /* I added this to test if it's gonna fix it, but it didn't */
}
```

When I click the link - it becomes blue. And it keeps being blue until I click somewhere else. So it's some highlighting or something. Or maybe it's hover color, that remains in browser, don't know. When I click out of the link it becomes gray, as it should.

Here's a video: http://youtu.be/EcTmJ_H4ozE

Comment: I think you are missing a:active - that's when the link you clicked still has focus.

Comment: For reference: [`:active`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active)

Comment: Tried `:active`. Didn't help. It's right when you click on link.

Comment: Why so many downvotes?

Comment: @SergeVinogradoff probably because this shows a lack of research

Comment: Once the link turns blue, inspect the element and see where it's is getting it's style from.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp) and nothing helped. So I tried `:link`, `:active`, `:visited` & `:hover` before posting. I did inspect it, but once I rightclick it turned grey, and CSS seemed to show it's grey. So I did research ) Problem was with `a:focus`.
Downvoters get a downvote to their karma for not reading carefully ;)

Answer (score -1):

You need jQuery for that here is a sample.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('yourlink').click(function(){
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});

<style>
.yourlink.active {color:gray}
<style>
```